# Magento 2 Add custom font to Email Template

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am adding custom font to Luma theme and followed this tutorials:
[Customize email templates](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html)

i have added fonts to *`{luma-theme-path}/web/fonts`*

`_typography.less` file :

```
.lib-font-face(  
    @family-name:@font-family-name__base,   
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}/fonts/my_font_name',  
    @font-weight: 400,  
    @font-style: normal  
);
```

updated `_variables.less` file for fonts as below:

```
// Fonts  
@font-family-name__base: 'my_family_name';  
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base;
```

i used `my_family_name` in Email templates css.
but this font does not applied on email.
I have also executed following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  
php bin/magento indexer:reindex  
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Order emails inherit the custom fonts that are defined by the frontend theme. Therefore, you can use custom fonts in your order emails that are already defined in your theme.

If the custom fonts are not defined in your frontend theme, then first follow the tutorial on how to add custom fonts to your theme described in the Magento [documentation ↗](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html).

Once your theme contains a new font, you need to update the **source/_variables.less** and **source/_typography.less** files for your custom theme to refer to the new font. For example,

```
@font-family__base: MyNewFont,sans-serif;
```

The same goes for the **Magento_Email/email/header.html** and **Magento_Email/email/footer.html** files. For example,

```
font-family:MyNewFont,sans-serif;
```

After updating, the emails should automatically use the specified font.

Tutorial from: https://themes.email/magento/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-magento-order-emails.html

Comment: "After updating, the emails should automatically use the specified font." 
Lol, adding custom font-family css in header.html is hardly 'automatic' ??!  :/